# Bounds for solve_ivp integration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode, numerical-integration

I have an ODE (for a phase space density) with a physical interpretation where the values should always be non-negative. Unfortunately, [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) uses large enough timesteps such that the values become negative. Forcing small timesteps would lead to a huge increase in computation time. So I'm looking for other ways to enforce the nonnegativity:

1. I looked at [solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html), but it seems like it can only enforce some linear S*y = 0 and not y > 0
2. Is there a way to change which steps in the solve_ivp integration are accepted/discarded?
3. Alternatively, is there a way to adapt the step size when the values are close to zero?

Thanks for any help,

Nik

Comment: Use `solve_ivp` with the Radau or LSODA implicit methods. Do you still get negative values? Did you select problem-relevant values for the tolerances `rtol, atol`? Alternatively, replace the density with `y=a*exp(b*u)` with sensibly chosen values for `a` and `b`, then `du/dt = dy/dt/(b*y)`. Then `y` can not become negative.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648878/replacing-negative-values for earlier discussions of this problem.